# Stanford corenlp convert Tree to IOB format

Tags: java, stanford-nlp

Is there a way to get StanfordCoreNLP Tree object output in IOB format instead of default output in folowing format:

```
(ROOT 
    (S 
        (NP 
            (NNP Stackoverflow)) 
        (VP 
            (VBZ is) 
            (NP 
                (DT a) 
                (JJ great) 
                (NN site))) 
        (. .)))
```